# How can I create a vector of objects while reading from a file? [c++]

Tags: c++, object, vector, overloading

Basically I am trying to create a vector of objects but I have to create the objects with information read from a file using the overloaded input stream operator for my class Voter.

main:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Voter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i = 0;
    int idNumber;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string hasVoted;
    vector<Voter> VoterVector;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("voters.txt");
    if(!inFile){
        cout << "Unable to open voters.txt" << endl;
    }
    inFile >> idNumber >> firstName >> lastName >> hasVoted;
    while(inFile) {
        Voter temp();
        temp >> idNumber >> firstName >> lastName >> hasVoted;
        VoterVector.push_back(temp);
        inFile >> idNumber >> firstName >> lastName >> hasVoted;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Voter class:

```
#ifndef VOTER_H
#define VOTER_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Voter {
public:
    Voter();
    virtual ~Voter();
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, Voter &v);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Voter &v);
private:
    int idNumber;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string hasVoted;
};
Voter::Voter() {
    this->idNumber = 0;
    this->firstName = '-none-';
    this->lastName = '-none-';
    this->hasVoted = 'FALSE';
}

Voter::~Voter() {
}

istream &operator>>(istream &in, Voter &v) {
    in >> v.idNumber >> v.firstName >> v.lastName >> v.hasVoted;
    return in;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Voter &v) {
    out << v.idNumber << endl << v.firstName << endl << v.lastName << endl        << v.hasVoted << endl;
    return out;
}
```

I keep getting errors with the way I create the objects and put them into the vector. I am pretty sure my overloading and reading from the file is done correctly, just not sure on the proper way to set up the vector of the objects. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That would be: `Voter temp; while (inFile >> temp) { VoterVector.push_back(temp); }`.

Comment: @0x499602D2: I'm going to start _flagging_ answers-in-comments. You're obviously not getting the message.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Oops! Got me again! lol

Answer (score 2):

```
Voter temp();
```

This is wrong. It declares a function.

Here's how you create a `Voter` object:

```
Voter temp;
```

Furthermore, you are doing strange things with that `>>` operator.

Why not simply:

```
int main()
{
    vector<Voter> voterVector;
    ifstream inFile("voters.txt");

    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "Unable to open voters.txt" << endl;
    }

    Voter temp;
    while (inFile >> temp) {
        voterVector.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```